# nestedSortable (toHierarchy) storing result in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm completely confused as to how I update the "sort" column on my database for elements that have children. The answers I've seen here and around the web only seem to deal with the parents and go no further than that.

I'm basically trying to build a sortable nested list using "nestedSortable". When the user releases the drag event an ajax call is triggered and the database is updated. I've had this working fine for single level (no parent) items but absolutely cannot fathom how to do this.

Database structure: id | parent | label | sort

JavaScript:

```
      $('ol.ROMenus').nestedSortable({
disableNesting: 'no-nest',
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
handle: 'div',
helper: 'clone',
items: 'li',
maxLevels: 3,
opacity: .6,
placeholder: 'placeholder',
revert: 250,
tabSize: 25,
tolerance: 'pointer',
toleranceElement: '> div',
update: function () {
    list = $(this).nestedSortable('toHierarchy');
    $.post(
        'includes/ajax/saveorder.inc.php',
        { order: list, section:"menus",side: menuSide },
        function(data){
            $("#ReOrderRes").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow')
        },
        "html"
    );
}
});
```

Output array from nestedSortable:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 24
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 15
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 28
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 36
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 37
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 38
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 39
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 40
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 41
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 42
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 67
    )

)
```

HTML Markup:

```
<ol class="ROMenus">
<li id="listItem-1"><div>About Us</div></li>
<li id="listItem-4"><div>Products</div>
    <ol>
        <li id="listItem-14"><div>Furniture</div>
<ol>
<li id="listItem-24"><div>Tables</div></li>
<li id="listItem-15"><div>Chairs</div></li>
<li id="listItem-28"><div>Cupboards</div></li>
</ol>
        </li>
        <li id="listItem-36"><div>Paints</div></li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

I've seen is to use a foreach loop, but this only covers the top parent items and doesn't ever touch the child elements:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) { #Do Something }
```

I'm not a PHP/MySQL newbie and have been developing for many years, but this one has me stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use recursive function to generate the HTML from the given array.

Comment: Hi Ahbik, yeah I've already managed to diplay the HTML perfectly. My problem is storing the new order when an item has the "children" sub-array using recursion, as you have pointed out. I just don't know where to start with that. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive list print

**Update**: this isn't what you were looking for - see other answer.

```php
function displayItem($item) {
   echo "<li id={$item['id']}>";
   if ($item['children']) {
       echo '<ol>'.displayItem( $item['children']).'</ol>';
   }
   echo "</li">;
}


echo "<ol>\n".displayItems($list)."</ol>";
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, vogo. I think maybe my question isn't very clear, what I'm really after is how to update the MySQL table with the new position of all items in the array, including the children. I know I need to use recursion for this but can't get my head around how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My apologies - you're submitting t

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has built-in capability for this kind of thing with the Tree model behavior. It sounds like a painful thing to roll yourself. You can do things like this:

```
//##From Docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html ##
$allChildren = $this->Category->children(1); // a flat array with 11 items
// -- or --
$this->Category->id = 1;
$allChildren = $this->Category->children(); // a flat array with 11 items

// Only return direct children
$directChildren = $this->Category->children(1, true); // a flat array with
                                                      // 2 items
```

And it's not difficult to set up. Here's a couple of tutorials:

http://www.cakephpexample.com/cakephp-basics/cakephp-tree-behavior-example/

http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/

And, if you've never used CakePHP, here's the blog tutorial, which seems to be everyone's first touchstone with that framework:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: If nothing else this has inspired me to look into cakePHP going forward, I had no idea you could just put the system in document root and not require server level access (something I don't have access to for any of our clients). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
function mapValues($data) {
   $str = '(' . 
       join( ',', 
           array( $data['id'], $data['label'], $data['sort'], $data['parent']) 
       . ')';
   return $str;
}

function updateList($data, $parent) {
    $list = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
       $list[] = array( 
               id => $value['id'], label => $value['label'], 
               sort => $key, parent => $parent);
       if ($value['children']) {
           $list = array_merge($list, updateList( $value['children'], $value['id']));
       }
    }
    return $list;
}

// this may have SQL injection issues - improve as necessary....

$list = updateList($myPostedData, 0);
$textList = join( ',', array_map( 'mapValues', $list));
$sql = <<<EOF
INSERT INTO myTable( id, label, parent, sort)
VALUES $textList
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id=VALUES(id), label=VALUES(label), 
    parent=VALUES(parent), sort=VALUES(sort)
EOF;

// run the SQL with your favourite mysqli/PDO or whatever library here...
```